# ruby on rails - Environment Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Environment variable

After installing rails in windows when I run command  in cmd it gets an error that

the system cannot find the path specified

and second when I run command  in cmd it gets an error that

> ERROR: could not find a valid gem 'railties' <= 4.2.3> here is why:
>
> unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect
>   returned=1 errorno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
>   certificate verify failed https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz

Answer (score 1):

You are likely behind a corporate proxy that is creating fake certificates for https sites so that it can sniff https traffic. The reason this usually works is that you have the corporate certificate as a trusted root on clients, but it doesn't work for Gem because it uses certificate pinning.

The solution is either

- adding the company certificate to the Gem trusted certificates: `SET SSL_CERT_FILE=c:\your\company\cert.pem`
- changing the Gem source in your Gemfile to http instead of https (`source 'https://rubygems.org'` to `source 'http://rubygems.org'`)
- turning off certificate validation (by adding `:ssl_verify_mode: 0` to your gemrc file, located on Windows in `%USERPROFILE%\.gemrc`)

Note that if you change the gem source to http or turn off certificate validation, an attacker may be able to tamper with the downloaded gems (change contents to arbitrary code). You should not normally do these.

Answer (score 1):

Go to command prompt, and input the following lines.

`gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/`

`gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/`, input `y` afterward.

Then you should be able to install `gem`.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows with PowerShell installed

Installing Windows PowerShell

Paste this 1line code in command console: (WIN + R, cmd)

```
powershell -Command "& {$fname='cacert.pem'; $outpath=\"$($(Get-ChildItem Env:USERPROFILE).Value)/$fname\"; Invoke-WebRequest http://curl.haxx.se/ca/$fname -OutFile \"$outpath\"; [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('SSL_CERT_FILE', \"$outpath\", 'User')}"
```

Script will do:

1. Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Save it as `%USERPROFILE%/cacert.pem ( C:\Users\__you__\cacert.pem)`
3. Set persistent environment variable for current user `SSL_CERT_FILE` as `%USERPROFILE%/cacert.pem`

After this try to install the gem